# Location Status Inconsistent Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to get the current location of user and show a marker on the MAP. Here is my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    Location mLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



        if (mLocation != null) {
            Log.i("Location Status: ", "Location Found");
        } else if (mLocation == null) {
            Log.i("Location Status: ", "Location Not Found");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(mLocation!=null) {
            try {
                Double lat = mLocation.getLatitude();
                Double lng = mLocation.getLongitude();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("My Location"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 12));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Location Error:","Exception was "+ex);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("My Location"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 12));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enable your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is that most of the times on I don't get any location, A map is shown without any marker and in the logs "Location Status:Location Not Found" which is set to be shown if location is null.
I tried to rebuild and run again. Now the location is detected on one device but it's showing the same awkward output on other devices. I want this to work every time but it's acting strange as the same code is showing two different behaviors on same device on different times with same settings.
P.S. Location is enabled on devices.
Any kind of help or tip will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code coded by me**

- Some time GPS can't able to locate your location that's why you getting **`null`** in  object of **`mLocation`**
- So my suggestion is to get `location` on bases of **NETWORK_PROVIDER** and also **`GPS_PROVIDER`**

***here is my code***

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location mLocation;
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            mLocation = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (mLocation == null) {
                mLocation = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
        }

        if (locationManager != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            if (mLocation != null) {
                Log.e("Location Status: ", "Location Found");
            } else {
                Log.e("Location Status: ", "Location Not Found");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        /*// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/

        if (mLocation != null) {
            try {
                Double lat = mLocation.getLatitude();
                Double lng = mLocation.getLongitude();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("My Location"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 12.5f));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Location Error:", "Exception was " + ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enable your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enable your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: okk :-) but don't forget click on right mark
if you have any query ask me